# log(odds) to p formulation

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

$$Log(Odds) = log({p \over (1-p)}) $$

$${p \over (1-p)} = e^{b+b_1x_1+....}$$

I understand up to here, however how does this:

$$p = (1-p) e^{b+b_1x_1+...}$$

become:

$$ p = {1 \over {1+e^{-(b+b_1x_1+...)}}}$$

Can someone explain last two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, $p = (1 - p)e^{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}$

Let $y= {b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}$

So, $p = (1 - p)e^y$

or, $p = e^y - pe^y$

or, $p+pe^y = e^y$

or, $p(1+e^y) = e^y$

or, $p = e^y/(1+e^y)$

or, $p = 1/(e^{-y}+1)$ (Dividing both denominator and numerator by $e^y$ on the RHS)

or, $p = 1/(e^{-{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}}+1)$

or, $p = 1/(1+e^{-{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}})$

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: How do we get $p(1-e^{y})$ ? as @Linxing Yao derived on RHS?

Comment: That should be $p(1+e^y)$. I think he has made a silly mistake there. Did you understand my answer @haneulkim?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$p = (1 - p)e^{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}$, then $p(1 + e^{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}) = e^{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}$, thus
\begin{align}
p &= \frac{e^{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}}{1 + e^{b + b_1x_1 + \ldots}} \\
  &= \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(b + b_1x_1 + \ldots)}}
\end{align}

Comment: could you elaborate formula between `then` and `thus`?

Comment: you can move the same factor p to the left side, it transits my first equation to the my second equation.

Comment: let $y = b+b_1x_1+...$I'm confused about how $p = (1-p)e^{y}$ becomes $p(1-e^{y}) = e^{y}$.